Session removal saga terminates prematurely when handling unauthorized requests
I'm encountering an issue with Redux-Saga where my session removal process is not completing fully when handling unauthorized (401) requests. Here's the scenario:

When a request receives a 401 (Unauthorized) response from the backend, it triggers a session removal process:

if (isAxiosError(error) && error.response?.status === RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE.UNAUTHORIZED) {
    yield* put(
        actions.startManageSession({
            sessionAction: SessionActions.removeSession,
        }),
    );

    return {
        responseData: null,
        responseError: { detail: 'Unauthorized' },
    };
}


This dispatches an action that's handled in session-saga.ts:

export function* manageSession(action: PayloadAction<any>) {
    const sessionAction: SessionActions = action.payload.sessionAction;
    // ...
    if (sessionAction === SessionActions.removeSession) {
        yield put(actions.setUserAccount(null));
        yield put(actions.setUserInfo(null));
        window.localStorage.removeItem(SESSION_NAME);
        // ... more removals ...
    }
    // ...
}

The problem is that only the first action in the removeSession block (setUserAccount(null)) is executed. The subsequent actions, including setUserInfo(null), are not run. This leads to an inconsistent state where authInfo is null but userInfo is not, causing issues in other parts of the application.
It appears that the moment the code reaches the return statement in the error handling block, it prematurely stops the saga, preventing the completion of the session removal process:
return {
    responseData: null,
    responseError: { detail: 'Unauthorized' },
};

Interestingly, if I add an artificial delay before returning in the error handling code, it works as expected:
if (isAxiosError(error) && error.response?.status === RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE.UNAUTHORIZED) {
    yield* put(
        actions.startManageSession({
            sessionAction: SessionActions.removeSession,
        }),
    );
    
    yield delay(5000); // This makes it work

    return {
        responseData: null,
        responseError: { detail: 'Unauthorized' },
    };
}

Why is the saga terminating prematurely when it hits the return statement, and how can I ensure that the entire session removal process completes before the error handling returns? I'd prefer a solution that doesn't rely on arbitrary delays.
Full Snippet
request.ts
async function request(
    url: string,
    options?: AxiosRequestConfig,
): Promise<{} | { err: AxiosError }> {
    const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
    if (!options) {
        options = { cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token };
    } else {
        options = Object.assign(options, {
            cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token,
        });
    }
    const promise = axios(url, options).then(parseJSON);

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    (promise as any)[CANCEL] = () => {
        // cancel XHR request, called by redux-saga when a saga gets cancelled
        cancelTokenSource.cancel(CANCEL_OPERATION);
    };

    return promise;
}

export function* genericRequest(
    url: URL,
    method: httpMethod,
    data: unknown = null,
    showNotification = true,
    params: object | null = null,
    calledWithSchema = noSchemaSymbol,
) {
    if (
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
        calledWithSchema !== withSchemaSymbol
    ) {
        console.log(
            `DEPRECATED: switch to requestWithSchema for type-safe requests (${method} ${url.pathname})\nIf you're working on this part of the code, consider updating the sagas`,
        );
    }
    const authUser = yield* select(selectAuthUser);

    if (!authUser) {
        console.trace('User not authenticated');

        return {
            responseData: null,
            responseError: {},
        };
    }
    const options = getOptions(method, data, authUser.accessToken, params);

    try {
        const response: GenericResponse = (yield* call(
            request,
            url.href,
            options,
        )) as GenericResponse;
        if (response.type === 4) {
            const responseError: GenericError = { detail: response.message };

            if (showNotification) {
                yield* put(
                    globalActions.addNotification({
                        type: CustomNotificationTypes.ERROR,
                        message: response.message || undefined,
                    }),
                );
            }

            return {
                responseData: null,
                responseError,
            };
        } else {
            return {
                responseData: response.data || true,
                responseError: null,
            };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        //refers to Warning code
        if (
            isAxiosError(error) &&
            error.response?.status === RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE.UNAUTHORIZED
        ) {
            yield* put(
                actions.startManageSession({
                    sessionAction: SessionActions.removeSession,
                }),
            );

            return {
                responseData: null,
                responseError: { detail: 'Unauthorized' },
            };
        }
        if (isAxiosError(error) && error.response?.data?.Type === 2) {
            const responseError: GenericError = {
                title: error.name,
                detail: error.response.data.Message,
                data: error.response.data.Data,
                status: error.response?.data.Type,
            };
            return {
                responseData: null,
                responseError,
            };
        } else {
            // refers to Error
            const responseError: GenericError = {
                title: error instanceof Error ? error.name : 'Unknown Error',
                detail: isAxiosError(error)
                    ? (error.response?.data?.Message ?? error.message)
                    : error instanceof Error
                        ? error.message
                        : undefined,
            };

            if (showNotification) {
                yield* put(
                    globalActions.addNotification({
                        type: CustomNotificationTypes.ERROR,
                        title: responseError.title,
                        message: responseError.detail ?? undefined,
                    }),
                );
            }
            return {
                responseData: null,
                responseError,
            };
        }
    }
}

session-saga.ts
export function* manageSession(action: PayloadAction<any>) {
    const sessionAction: SessionActions = action.payload.sessionAction;
    const accessToken = action.payload.accessToken;

    try {
        if (sessionAction === SessionActions.getSession) {
            const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem(SESSION_NAME);
            const session = accessToken&& JSON.parse(accessToken);
            const { userAccount, userInfo } = mapUser(session.accessToken);
            if (!userAccount || !userInfo) {
                yield put(
                    actions.manageSessionError({ detail: SessionErrors.invalidToken }),
                );
                return;
            }
            yield put(actions.setUserAccount(userAccount));
            yield put(actions.setUserInfo(userInfo));
            yield put(actions.sessionLoadedFromLocalStorage());
            yield put(actions.loadInitData());
        } else if (sessionAction === SessionActions.removeSession) {
            yield put(actions.setUserAccount(null));
            yield put(actions.setUserInfo(null));
            window.localStorage.removeItem(SESSION_NAME);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(FILTERS_FOR_CONTRACTS);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(FILTERS_FOR_OFFERS);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(FILTERS_FOR_REVIEW_AND_RELEASE);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(FILTERS_FOR_ORIGINATOR_SCREEN);
        } else if (sessionAction === SessionActions.setSession && accessToken) {
            const { userAccount, userInfo } = mapUser(accessToken);
            if (!userAccount || !userInfo) {
                yield put(
                    actions.manageSessionError({ detail: SessionErrors.invalidToken }),
                );
                return;
            }
            window.localStorage.setItem(
                SESSION_NAME,
                JSON.stringify({ accessToken: accessToken }),
            );

            //save the initial filter DATA at localStorage
            Object.entries(initialFilters).forEach(([key, value]) =>
                localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value)),
            );

            yield put(actions.setUserAccount(userAccount));
            yield put(actions.setUserInfo(userInfo));
            yield put(actions.sessionFromService());
            yield put(actions.loadInitData());
            yield put(actions.getCommoditiesCropYearsExpired());
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(
            actions.manageSessionError({
                detail: error instanceof Error ? error.message : null,
            }),
        );
    }
}


